# Nepenthes ventrata

Tags: pruning

Ours is about 5.5 ft tall growing in a tomato cage for support. We winter it in our small greenhouse. This spring we cut off the old pitchers and want to know if we should remove the old tall stems to make way for the new growth coming up from the base?  We are in zone 7 and house our plant in our dappled shade back yard during spring thru early fall.